# Calling superclass in main method

Tags: java, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I've just learned about superclasses and subclasses and the homework is pretty simple: have 2 classes and a test class to call and print the attributes. Below is my code from all 3 classes. My question is, why isn't the department attributes printing in my main? Everything else prints just fine, I just can't get that last little bit to print. I think it has something to do with super...thank you in advance! Second computer course and I'm finally feeling I sort of get it, so that's improvement from the first class I took!

```
public class Employee {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int employeeID;
    private double salary;

    public Employee () {

        firstName = null;
        lastName = null;
        employeeID = 0;
        salary = 0.00;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID(int employeeID) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String employeeSummary () {
        String employeeSummary = "Employee's name is: " + getFirstName() + " " + getLastName() +
                    ". The employee's ID number is " + getEmployeeID() + 
                    ". The employee's salary is " + getSalary();
        System.out.println(employeeSummary);
        return employeeSummary;
    }

}


public class Manager extends Employee {

    private String departmentA;

    public Manager() {
        super();
        departmentA = null;
    }

    public String getDepartmentA() {
        return departmentA;
    }

    public void setDepartmentA(String departmentA) {
        this.departmentA = departmentA;
    }

    public void EmployeeSummary() {
        super.employeeSummary();
        System.out.println("The employee's department is " + departmentA);
    }
}


public class ManagerDerivation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Manager person = new Manager();

        person.setFirstName("Ron");
        person.setLastName("Weasley");
        person.setEmployeeID(2345);
        person.setSalary(65000.00);
        person.setDepartmentA("Department of Magical Law Enforcement");
        person.employeeSummary();

    return;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some spelling (employeeSummary vs. EmployeeSummary) mistakes and return types dont match, in Employee should be

```
public void employeeSummary () {
    String employeeSummary = "Employee's name is: " + getFirstName() + " " + 
    getLastName() +
                ". The employee's ID number is " + getEmployeeID() + 
                ". The employee's salary is " + getSalary();
    System.out.println(employeeSummary);   
}
```

then in Manager

```
public void employeeSummary() {
    super.employeeSummary();
    System.out.println("The employee's department is " + departmentA);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method names are case sensitive.  `EmployeeSummary()` does not override `employeeSummary()` because it uses a different name.

To avoid mistakes like this, always include the [`@Override` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) on overridden methods.  If you include that annotation and make a mistake in the method signature, compilation will fail.

Note also that your return types for the two methods are different (`String` and `void`).  Overridden methods must have compatible return types.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I thought about putting @Override but wasn't sure if that was what was needed or not. Thanks so much! I truly appreciate it :)